# What is the proper future tense conjugation for 'decir'?

Tags: gramática

A course at Memrise.com says the future tense conjugation of 'decir' is as follows:

> Yo diré
>
> Tú dirás
>
> Él dirá
>
> Nosotros diremos
>
> Ellos dirán

However, the audio that goes along with the course speaks:

> Yo deciré
>
> Tú decirás
>
> Él decirá
>
> Nosotros deciremos
>
> Ellos decirán

Someone help me! Which is the proper conjugation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every question about proper verb conjugations can be answered visiting the [RAE web](http://www.rae.es/) and looking up the infinitive ("[decir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BxLriBU)"). Press the blue "conjugar" button and *voilá*:

```
yo                     diré
tú / vos               dirás
usted / él, ella       dirá
nosotros, nosotras     diremos
vosotros, vosotras     diréis
ustedes / ellos, ellas dirán
```

The "deciré" form would be the conjugation were the verb a regular one, but it is not.

Check out [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/resources-for-learning-spanish?cb=1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. The audio within the Memrise course sounds like it uses native speakers. I wouldn't expect a native speaker to intentionally record his or her voice speaking an improper conjugation! This is why I was so confused.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson then it looks like you found a troll (they are everywhere). Maybe you can flag the voice record as inaccurate.